# What does "for" mean in the second-to-last verse of the last stanza of Eric Bogle's "The Green Fields of France"?

Tags: prepositions, syntax

The song "*The Green Fields of France*", written by Eric Bogle, ends with:

> **For** young Willie McBride, it* all happened again,
> and again and again and again and again.

*war, the song is about World War One, the "war to end wars"

What does "for" mean in this context? Many versions of the song replace that "for" with "oh", but there is "for" in the original version. Should that be read as "This is a message for young Willie McBride...", or?

Answer (score 2):

From Oxford Dictionary of English:

> **for** *preposition*
> **2** affecting, with regard to, or in respect of

So in your context, and knowing that "it" means war, that line means roughly,

> From the perspective of young Willie McBride, war didn't end, but happened over and over again.